# Popup / modal when submitting a form, depending on what information has been entered into the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, modal-dialog, popup

I'm looking for advice on the best way to implement a popup / modal on form submit in Ruby/Rails.

I have a simple form, with a submit button, which works as expected (updates the relevant fields in the database).

I have been given additional requirements: Depending on the information that is input into the form, when submitting the form there should be a modal / popup. An overview of the different requirements for this are below:

1. When certain fields are updated but the information conflicts an earlier update (for example, a date field is updated, but a different date has already been set previously), a popup / modal with an error will appear, and when clicking OK will return to the form with any input still in place (i.e. does not refresh the form). There are three different scenarios with three different error types, so three different error messages are needed.
2. When certain fields are updated but others are left blank, a popup / modal with an 'Are you sure?' type message will appear. Again there are three different scenarios, so three different messages needed. There will be Cancel and OK buttons: Cancel will return to the form with any input still in place, OK will submit the form.
3. Finally, if the form is updated with no issues (i.e. none of the above are true), then the form will submit with no popup / modal (i.e. a standard form submit).

I've looked into creating modals, but because of the seven different scenarios/requirements I have, I'm struggling to find a suitable way in which to implement this. The first thing that comes to mind is that there will be a lot of if-statements, but I feel there must be a more effective way to do it. There are a couple of modals in the code that I have looked at (which were done before I took over the project), which use button_tag, but I don't know if I would want to use the same format in a form.

Comment: Lot of documentation to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you first scenario, you could look at implementing your own validtions on your ActiveRecord Model, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods. Form data gets submitted via AJAX, check your JSON response for any errors, show the modal with the errors if any.

For the second scenario, I would add client side validations. Have your JS check the fields when the form is being submitted, if they're empty, show the 'Are you sure?' modal. If they click 'Yes', then we go to scenario one checking for any errors.

Lastly, if the form is submitted successfully, clear all the fields via JS and show a success message.